# (TF-IDF)How to return the five related article after calculating cosine similarity

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf, nlp-question-answering

I get a dataframe *sample_df*(4 columns: *paper_id*,*title*,*abstract*,*body_text*). I extracted the abstract column(~1000 words per abstract) and apply the text cleaning process. Here's my question:

After finished calculating the cosine similarity between question and abstract, how can it return the top5 articles score with corresponding information(e.g. *paper_id*,*title*,*body_text*) since my goal is to do tf -idf question answering.

I'm really sorry that my english is poor and I am new to nlp. I would appreciated if someone can help.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity  

txt_cleaned = get_cleaned_text(sample_df,sample_df['abstract'])
question = ['Can covid19 transmit through air']

tfidf_vector = TfidfVectorizer()

tfidf = tfidf_vector.fit_transform(txt_cleaned)

tfidf_question = tfidf_vector.transform(question)
cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(tfidf_question,tfidf).flatten()

related_docs_indices = cosine_similarities.argsort()[:-5:-1]
cosine_similarities[related_docs_indices]

#output([0.18986527, 0.18339485, 0.14951123, 0.13441914])
```

Comment: how about `[-5:]` ? And maybe `txt_cleaned[  related_docs_indices[0] ]` `txt_cleaned[  related_docs_indices[1] ]`, etc. ? Or maybe `sample_df[ [  related_docs_indices[0] ]`, `sample_df[ [  related_docs_indices[1] ]`, etc.

Comment: #output like this ([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.12426738, 0.12570496,
       0.12707237])  The main problem is how to get the other information back(the columns in **sample_df** e.g. paper_id, abstract..., but not  the cosine_similarities. I am confused that what is the next step.

Comment: if `sample_df` is a list then `sample_df[ [  related_docs_indices[0] ]`, etc.

Comment: `sample_df` is a dataframe. `sample_df ={ 'paper_id':[xxx,yyy], 'title': [xx,yy], 'abstract':[xx,yy],'body_text:[xx,yy] }`

Comment: if it dataframe then use `iloc` to get row by number. `sample_df.iloc[  related_docs_indices[0] ]`, `sample_df.iloc[  related_docs_indices[1] ]`, etc. and maybe even 5 rows `sample_df.iloc[ related_docs_indices[:5] ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: if you want 5 articles then instead of `[:-5:-1]` you have to use `[:-6:-1]` because for negative values it works little different.

Or use `[::-1][:5]` - `[::-1]` will reverse all values and then you can use normal `[:5]`

---

When you have `related_docs_indices` then you can use `.iloc[]` to get elements from `DataFrame`

```
 sample_df.iloc[ related_docs_indices ]
```

If you will have elements with the same similarity then it will gives them in reversed order.

---

**BTW:**

You can also add `similarities` to `DataFrame`

```
sample_df['similarity'] = cosine_similarities
```

and then sort (reversed) and get 5 items.

```
sample_df.sort_values('similarity', ascending=False)[:5]
```

If you will have elements with the same similarity then it will gives them in original order.

---

Minimal working code with some data - so everyone can copy and test it.

Because I have only 5 elements in `DataFrame` so I search 2 elements.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity  

import pandas as pd

sample_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'paper_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'title': ['Covid19', 'Flu', 'Cancer', 'Covid19 Again', 'New Air Conditioners'],
    'abstract': ['covid19', 'flu', 'cancer', 'covid19', 'air conditioner'],
    'body_text': ['Hello covid19', 'Hello flu', 'Hello cancer', 'Hello covid19 again', 'Buy new air conditioner'],
})

def get_cleaned_text(df, row):
    return row

txt_cleaned = get_cleaned_text(sample_df, sample_df['abstract'])
question = ['Can covid19 transmit through air']

tfidf_vector = TfidfVectorizer()

tfidf = tfidf_vector.fit_transform(txt_cleaned)

tfidf_question = tfidf_vector.transform(question)
cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(tfidf_question,tfidf).flatten()

sample_df['similarity'] = cosine_similarities

number = 2
#related_docs_indices = cosine_similarities.argsort()[:-(number+1):-1]
related_docs_indices = cosine_similarities.argsort()[::-1][:number]

print('index:', related_docs_indices)

print('similarity:', cosine_similarities[related_docs_indices])

print('\n--- related_docs_indices ---\n')

print(sample_df.iloc[related_docs_indices])

print('\n--- sort_values ---\n')

print( sample_df.sort_values('similarity', ascending=False)[:number] )
```

Result:

```
index: [3 0]
similarity: [0.62791376 0.62791376]

--- related_docs_indices ---

   paper_id          title abstract            body_text  similarity
3         4  Covid19 Again  covid19  Hello covid19 again    0.627914
0         1        Covid19  covid19        Hello covid19    0.627914

--- sort_values ---

   paper_id          title abstract            body_text  similarity
0         1        Covid19  covid19        Hello covid19    0.627914
3         4  Covid19 Again  covid19  Hello covid19 again    0.627914
```

Comment: It works! The result is same as what I expected! Thank you so much!!!